# android webview not functioning on a page with websockets

Tags: android, webview

I have a chat web application on spring mvc. I used android webview to get to that chat page, which is using websockets. I can see the page on the android webview but when I type and click send it doesn't respond. This page works fine when i deploy it on the browser using jetty.

```
        webview= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webscreen);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);              
        webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);       
        webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webview.setClickable(true);
        webview.setLongClickable(true);        
        webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);     
        webview.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/mychat/chatwindow");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new DroidWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look around on the web, you'll see lots of information about the [Android web browser not supporting sockets](http://mobilehtml5.org/). The `WebView` is no different.